# JavaScript array of objects contains the same array data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to get all same data values into an array of objects. This is my input:

```js
var a = [{
    name: "Foo",
    id: "123",
    data: ["65d4ze", "65h8914d"]
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    id: "321",
    data: ["65d4ze", "894ver81"]
  }
]
```

I need a result like:

```
["65d4ze"]
```

I try to loop on my object to get this output, but I'm completely lost... I don't know how to know if the result is into all data arrays.

```js
var a = [{
        name: "Foo",
        id: "123",
        data: ["65d4ze", "65h8914d"]
      },
      {
        name: "Bar",
        id: "321",
        data: ["65d4ze", "894ver81"]
      }
    ],
  b = [],
  c = []
a.forEach(function(object) {
  b.push(object.data.map(function(val) {
    return val;
    })
  );
});

console.log(b);
```

Comment: So get all arrays elements that are present on all `a`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: @JamesLong I don't understand the duplication, why this answer can help me ?

Comment: @Eddie I need to get all array into the key data. This key is present into all object of my principal array.

Comment: @Kamoulox you have 2 arrays (a[0].data and a[1].data). You seem to be wanting an array of all the values that appear in both arrays. Unless I'm mis-reading your question

Comment: @Kamoulox didn't get this line  "I don't know how to know if the result is into all data array.". If you can clarify, then I can help

Comment: So it doesnt matter if the array has 2 objects or more than 2 right? Correct me if I were wrong.  @Kamoulox

Comment: @tnkh Yes and the answer of Nina Scholz give me a perfect way to do that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could map `data` and get the common values with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).

```js
var array = [{ name: "Foo", id: "123", data: ["65d4ze", "65h8914d"] }, { name: "Bar", id: "321", data: ["65d4ze", "894ver81"] }],
    key = 'data',
    common = array
        .map(o => o[key])
        .reduce((a, b) => b.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(a)));

console.log(common);
```

Comment: I have some troubles to understand this piece of code `b.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(a))`. But it's working perfectly, thanks

Comment: `filter` has two parameters, one foir the callback, which is here a prototype function of `Set`, `has` which checks a value against a set. at this point, the method does not works because it need an instance of `Set`. the second parameter is `thisArg`, where you can hand over an object, which is used as `this` in the callback. mabe a different use makes ir a bet more clear. you could gate the same with a bound `this` by using this as callback: `Set.prototype.has.bind(new Set(a))`, which is now a function with `this`.

Comment: With array `common = array
        .map(o => o[key])
        .reduce((a, b) => b.filter(Array.prototype.includes, a));`

Comment: @PranavCBalan, [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) uses a second parameter `fromIndex` and gets this value with the index of the callback ...

Comment: @NinaScholz : oops that's right, that would make issues  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. Filter the first array by checking if a value is present in all other object properties (arrays), using the [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check if a value is present in all remaining arrays.

```
let res = a[0].data.filter(v => a.slice(1).every(a => a.data.includes(v)));
```

```js
var a = [{
    name: "Foo",
    id: "123",
    data: ["65d4ze", "65h8914d"]
  },
  {
    name: "Bar",
    id: "321",
    data: ["65d4ze", "894ver81"]
  }
];

let res = a[0].data.filter(v => a.slice(1).every(a => a.data.includes(v)));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = [{
      name: "Foo",
      id: "123",
      data: ["65d4ze", "65h8914d"]
    },
    {
      name: "Bar",
      id: "321",
      data: ["65d4ze", "894ver81"]
    }
  ],
  b = {};
a.forEach(function(i) {
  i.data.forEach(function(j) {
    if (!b.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
      b[j] = 0;
    }
    b[j] = b[j] + 1;
  });
});
c = []
for (var i in b) {
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    if (b[i] > 1) {
      c.push(i)
    }
  }
}
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `flat` function in the array:

```js
var a = [{
        name: "Foo",
        id: "123",
        data: ["65d4ze", "65h8914d"]
      },
      {
        name: "Bar",
        id: "321",
        data: ["65d4ze", "894ver81"]
      }
    ],
  b = [],
  c = []
a.forEach(function(object) {
  b.push(object.data.map(function(val) {
    return val;
    })
  );
});

console.log(b.flat());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that a great code. But `flat` is not working on my browser

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` and `concat` on each data array, and check the count of each item.

In the end, you check whether all objects across the array contain that item and return it if yes.

Note that this function works if you want to extract the item that has the same occurrence across all objects in the array.

If an item has duplicates, but does not fulfill the above condition, it would not be extracted.

```js
let a = [{name: "Foo",id: "123",data: ["65d4ze", "65h8914d"]},{name: "Bar",id: "321",data: ["65d4ze", "894ver81"]}]

let arr = a.reduce((prev,next) => prev.data.concat(next.data))
let counts = {};
let result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var num = arr[i];
  counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
}

for (let i in counts) {
    if (counts[i] === a.length) {
        result.push(i)
    }
}
console.log(result)
```